# suppress gfortran warning message

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Does anyone know if there is an option to suppress the following warning message
from gfortran:

```
Warning: Extension: Conversion from HOLLERITH to INTEGER(4) at (1)
```

(Without changing the code, that is).

I have already tried the options: `-Wno-conversion-extra -Wno-conversion`

I'm using gfortran 4.9.1 by the way.

Comment: You'll want to find an option to suppress warnings about using non-standard language extensions.

Comment: I am not sure this particular option exist.

Comment: `gfortran ... | grep -v HOLLERITH`

Comment: Please, don't suppress warnings. Warnings are there to help, it's much better to fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try this way:

`-std=legacy`

This may suppress the warning information as you mentioned since Hollerith constant is the legacy feature before FORTRAN77. However, **downside** of using this option is that all the possible legacy collision may not be shown. I have tested this option on gfortran 6.2.0.

Comment: Actually in my case, I don't know how to suppress another warning message related to Hollerith constant: The Hollerith constant at (1) is too long to convert to ‘REAL(4)’

Comment: You can try to ask in a question. But you will have to show the code too. But Holleriths are tricky, especially with non-integers.